# Excel table refresh Access query with defined parameters

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010, excel-2010

I am trying to connect an excel data table to an access query where the access 2010 query has a defined set of parameters ([StartDate] and [EndDate]). I need to pass parameters from Excel to Access to reduce the scope of the data which needs to be summarised from the granular data.

The Access Query is made up to summarise a granular data by date and various other groupings; this query due to the way I have to snapshot specific information requires a secondary query set which is a XTAB.

On both the Primary Query I want to Return and the XTAB I have a defined parameter e.g. [StartDate] and [EndDate] defined as Date/Time. This is used in the WHERE clause for both data sets on the ReportDate field.

When running this in access I am prompted for [StartDate] and [EndDate] and the results are displayed exactly as expected.

My query looks something like (and lets refer to this as the OUTPUT_QRY):

```
  PARAMETERS [StartDate] DateTime, [EndDate] DateTime;
  SELECT [TABLE_1].[ReportDate],
         [TABLE_1].[GroupA] AS CATEGORY_A, 
         [TABLE_1].[GroupB] AS CATEGORY_B, 
         [TABLE_1].[GroupC] AS CATEGORY_C, 
         SUM([TABLE_1].[values]) TOTAL_VOLUME
         SUM([XTAB_2].[0]) GROUP_0_VOLUME
         SUM([XTAB_2].[1]) GROUP_1_VOLUME
  FROM [TABLE_1]
       INNER JOIN [XTAB_2] ON [XTAB_2].[SnapshotKEY] = [TABLE_1].[SnapshotKEY]
  WHERE [TABLE_1].REPORT_DATE BETWEEN [StartDate] and [EndDate]
  GROUP BY [TABLE_1].[ReportDate],
           [TABLE_1].[GroupA] AS CATEGORY_A, 
           [TABLE_1].[GroupB] AS CATEGORY_B, 
           [TABLE_1].[GroupC] AS CATEGORY_C
```

XTAB_2 is a summary of related data snapshot information for the same level of data on the SnapshotKey. The main aim of OUTPUT_QRY is to summarise snapshot data we have at a higher level. Using a XTAB is more efficient than having 200+ calculated columns. XTAB_2 also contains the first line from the above query (PARAMETERS [StartDate] DateTime, [EndDate] DateTime) to also limit the scope of certain snapshot groupings we have.

Without the parameters XTAB_2 attempts to summarise all 6m rows of data before applying the inner join from TABLE_1 which takes significant time. The parameters are there to limit the scope of data to be converted into a crosstab query.

When I run this 'OUTPUT_QRY' it prompts for the [StartDate] and [EndDate], which I enter, and it clearly applies the Parameters to the where clause of OUTPUT_QRY and the where clause in the linked XTAB query. As above this works flawlessly in Access.

I need to provide a method to connect to this data from Excel. I have used the trick to go to Data -> Other Sources -> From Microsoft Query; Connect to the Database; Return any old standalone table; finally edit the data tables 'Connection Properties' Definition Table to:

```
 SELECT OUTPUT_QRY.* FROM OUTPUT_QRY
```

I am prompted with:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2
```

So I try:

```
SELECT OUTPUT_QRY.* FROM OUTPUT_QRY WHERE 1=? AND 2=?
```

And now it states:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 4
```

It seems like it's not passing whatever it is I want to pass into the defined parameters and now treating 1=? and 2=? as new parameters? I need the capability to refresh this data as/when needed between specific dates once we have completed processing data on a daily basis to enable an end user to query the millions of rows of information and have it in a nice layout so they can summarise/query further within their only available tool of excel.

Note, I am aware this should be solutioned in a more robust environment than Access 2010 but unfortunately due to restrictions this is the only solution available to us and have no other viable options. Any suggestions on this approach would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Comment: edited the example query to ensure consistency.

Comment: Can't have dynamic parameters in query linking to.

Comment: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/13/parameters-in-excel-external-data-queries/

This suggests you can do what I'm attempting but replacing [Enter a start date] and [Enter and end date] with 1=? and 2=? should pass the value to the prompted order of defined parameters in the query.

Comment: I got this far. `WHERE Report_Date BETWEEN ? AND ?` and get 'Enter parameter value' popups. I enter values and then get the 'too few parameters' error. All this approach seems to do is build a parameterized query in Excel, not pass any inputs to parameters in Access query. When I do this with a table, it works - the dataset is filtered. So back to my original assertion.

Comment: Can build SQL statement that joins tables and aggregates. I copy/pasted SQL and query worked. Excel didn't like my alias name, changed it to Expr1000.

Comment: Hmm, frustraiting. I think I may have to build a query to flag dates in scope for reporting in my date table and have a front on excel to request them to 'set' the date range required with flags to get around this. An extra something to consider but at least I know that'll work almost flawlessly.... Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Why even involve Excel?